# SnapPy isometry routine

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds, snappy

Dear Colleagues and Friends,

Here's a question that I hope some of you, more experienced in programming, can answer.

Once SnapPy is used to compute the symmetry group of a hyperbolic manifold by way of, say,

> K = Manifold('4_1');
>
> S = K.symmetry_group();

it outputs the action of the isometries on the cusps as

> S.isometries()

```
[0 -> 0
[1 0] 
[0 1] 
Extends to link, 
0 -> 0
[-1 0]
[ 0 1]
Extends to link, 
0 -> 0
[1 0] 
[0 1] 
Extends to link, ... etc
```

As you may imagine, the 0th entry is the identity map (a good one to start the list with), but the 2nd one is not, although its action on the cusp is trivial (SnapPy also says it's an involution, since S.multiply_elements(2,2) returns 0).

Is there a way to see the symmetry group action on the rest of the manifold in this case (as a callable method within SnapPy)?

Cheers,
Sasha

Comment: Yes, there is.  I'm not as familiar with the Python interface to SnapPy. There could be something there for you (but I don't see it in the docs).  In the underlying C code you have access to how the tetrahedra are permuted.  One not-too-pretty way to get access to what you want (this is what I use) is to retriangulate to the canonical triangulation. Save the canonical triangulation, load it into Regina, then call findAllIsomorphisms().

Comment: @RyanBudney: Hi Ryan, thanks for your reply. In Regina, however, can I also see the action of those isomorphisms on the cusps? The finicky thing is that I need to see both :-P

Comment: Yes, you can.  In regina an ideal triangulation is just a triangulation where some of the vertex links are surfaces beyond spheres or discs.   So in a cusped hyperbolic 3-manifold they would be tori or klein bottles.   So all you have to do is check which vertices are ideal (there is the isIdeal() call) to see how they are permuted.   To check if you have a translation action or mirror reflection you'll have to do a little work as Regina does not find the geometric structure on the cusp, but it's certainly a managable task.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Good to know. Thanks, Ryan!

Comment: @RyanBudney: Another (may be stupid) question: if N is a non-orientable triangulation, and M is its orientation cover, how are the pre-images of tetrahedron i in N numbered in M? 2*i - 1 and 2*i? Or it's a more complicated numbering? Having such things traceable would be extremely helpful even without more advanced functions, when it comes to see quotients of manifolds by their symmetries, etc, I think.

Comment: Does Regina have an orientation cover routine?  I don't see one in the docs.  But perhaps I'm looking in the wrong location. Usually for constructions like this, the ordering of the simplices is described in the documentation.  I would imagine they are either side-by-side, or the "bottom" simplices are all first, and their translates appear after that, in the same relative order as in the original triangulation.  If you can find the routine, let me know and I can tell you how it works.

Comment: Found it, makeDoubleCover().  If your original non-orientable manifold has tetrahedra 0,1,...,n-1, then the double cover with have tetrahedra 0,1,...,2n-1, and the translate of the i-th tetrahedron will be the i+n-th tetrahedron.

Comment: @RyanBudney: great info! Apparently it's different in SnapPea (or may be I misunderstood the C code -- that's _highly_ possible my mistake). Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ryan says, "isomorphisms of triangulations" are computed under the hood in snappy (and that is how it computes symmetry groups).  However, this functionality is not shown to the user.

If you have a convincing use case, you could contact Nathan Dunfield and Marc Culler with your request.

Comment: Hi Sam! Thanks for the suggestion.